# facing internet issues after enable manual proxy in mobile for recording mobile performance testing using jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I need to record the flow of application is inside the teams app follows the steps given below if I miss any extra step kindly let me know

I have to record HTTP traffic on my mobile phone with JMeter to do so I added HTTP(s) Test Script Recorder to Test Plan and set the port inside recorder to 8888. I also added Recording Controller inside Thread Group then I clicked Start button inside HTTP Proxy Server to generate certificate, after that I used ipconfig in the cmd to get my computer's IP address.

On my mobile I install transferred JMeter certificate and modify Wi-Fi network by setting parameter Proxy settings to Manual and typing IP of the computer as a hostname and 8888 as proxy port.

According to the instructions on the Internet, this configuration should allow me to record traffic on the phone, but nothing like that happens. It seems to me that something may be wrong with the proxy settings, because after I manually configured proxy the phone is offline. Does anyone know what the cause could be and how to fix this problem?

if i change my wifi public to private its working or not?

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all take a look at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), it normally contains enough details in order to get to the bottom of the issue, if it doesn't - you can [increase JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) for at least HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

   ```
   <Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy" level="debug" />
   ```
2. JMeter itself needs to be able to connect to the Internet so if you're behind a corporate proxy - you need to [make JMeter aware of this proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server)
3. In case of HTTPS protocol you will also need to take some extra steps:

   - for iOS you need to [enable full trust](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204477) for JMeter's certificate
   - for Android you will need to amend your application [network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config)
4. And last but not the least make sure that your computer's [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)) allows incoming TCP connections to port 8888